# Performance - MySQL default sorting order on inserting records

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

The default ordering ID of records in mysql is ASC (i.e. Rows that i insert goes down the table) but we'll be using only the latest information from the table (i.e. Rows that are below).

Will there be any performance improvements if we change the default ordering to DESC (i.e New records goes to the top of the table) and frequent information will be queried from top of the table.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be the opposite.

I'm basing this comment on how I understand indexes to work in SQL Server-I'll try to revise later if I get a chance to read up more on how they work in MySQL.

There could be a slight performance advantage to insert your rows in the same order as your index is sorted, versus inserting them in the opposite order.

If you insert in the same order, and your next row to insert is always greater in sort order than existing rows then you will always find the next available empty spot (when one exists) in your last page of rows data.

If you do the opposite, always have your next insert row lesser in sort order than existing rows then you will probably always have a collision in your first page of rows data and the engine will do a tad bit more work to shift the position of rows if the page has room for it.

As for your order by clause in the select statement:
1) there's nothing in the SQL standard about indexes, and nothing that guarantees your result set ordering except for the ORDER BY clause. Normally queries in SQL Server that use just one index will see results returned in the order of the index. But if the isolation level changes to "read uncommitted" (chaos?) then it will return rows in more likely in the order it finds them in memory or on disk which is not necessarily the order you want.

2) If the order by in your select statement is based on the exact same column criteria as the index, then your database server should perform the same with either the index order, or the opposite of the index order. This is pretty straightforward except perhaps if you have a multi-column index with mixed ASC-DESC declarations for different columns. You get away with equal performance with order by equal to index order and with order by equal to inverse index order where the inverse index order is determined by substituting the ASC and DESC declarations (explicit and implicit) in the index declaration with DESC and ASC in the order by clause.

Answer (score 1):

Any performance change would be on querying the records, not inserting one.

For queries, I doubt this will have much affect as database queries by keys usually have similar speeds.

It also depends on your data so I would run some tests.

Comment: Yes..! Now i have to query with ORDER BY `field` DESC all the time.. if i change the way it inserts i don't have to use ORDER BY right... might that be a performance boost... Yes and i would do performance test's for sure.. Just want to know if any one has seen significant change in performance